# Django, Create-react-app, Heroku

Tags: django, reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I have 3 folders in a Django web application.  The folders are as follows: the folder that contains settings.py(project), the folder that contains models.py(application), and a folder that contains a front end react application created by create-react-app.

I would like to build the react front end, copy the build artifacts into a static folder and then run the django application on heroku, but they have made this process practically impossible with my current folder structure.  The alternative is to flatten the react application out and have build, src, node_modules, packagejson etc etc etc all at the root of the project, but  this seems really bad.

Some config in settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'front-end/build/static')
```

)

What I run locally inside front-end:

```
npm run build
```

What I'm returning from views:

```
def index(request):

    return HttpResponse(loader.get_template('build/index.html').render())
    #above line returns index.html that is generated by npm run build
```

How do I deploy the project described above to Heroku so it can find all static resources?

Comment: A real pitty nobody answered. I have a similar problem with Ruby.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida for Rails I found these two nice tutorials (which I want to transfer to Django to answer this question…) – https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-get-create-react-app-to-work-with-your-rails-api/ and https://medium.com/superhighfives/a-top-shelf-web-stack-rails-5-api-activeadmin-create-react-app-de5481b7ec0b

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) link that puts your react's build output into your django directory

For example if your directory structure is like this:

```
~/project_root/
~/project_root/django/static/
~/project_root/my_react_app/build
```

cd to `~/project_root/django/static/` and run

```
ln -s ../../my_react_app/build .
```

This will create `~/project_root/django/static/build` that points to `~/project_root/my_react_app/build`